# html5 Canvas filltext with a certain alpha and background with a different alpha

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, globalcompositeoperation

I'm trying to draw text to a canvas with a certain alpha level and clip the text and draw a background color with it's own alpha level:

```
ctx.globalCompositeOperation = '...';
    ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(' + fgcolor.r + ', ' +  fgcolor.g + ', ' + fgcolor.b + ',' + (fgcolor.a / 255.0) + ')';
       ctx.fillText(String.fromCharCode(chr), x,y);
ctx.globalCompositeOperation = '...';
    ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(' + bgcolor.r + ', ' +  bgcolor.g + ', ' + bgcolor.b + ',' + (bgcolor.a / 255.0) + ')';
    ctx.fillRect(x, y, chr_width, chr_height);
```

I've tried playing with globalCompositeOperation and beginPath but I have been unable to achieve the desired result. I would also like to avoid drawImage and off screen canvases as speed is a major concern.

Comment: Please clarify what you desire.

Comment: I essentially want to draw text character on canvas using filltext and create a clipping region out of it to draw the background. This way the foreground character can have an alpha level and the background color can have it's own alpha level. Think of a dos console where each cell has a foreground color and a background color.

Answer (score 1):

This function will convert RGBA colors to RGB:

```
function RGBAtoRGB(r, g, b, a, backgroundR,backgroundG,backgroundB){
  var r3 = Math.round(((1 - a) * backgroundR) + (a * r))
  var g3 = Math.round(((1 - a) * backgroundG) + (a * g))
  var b3 = Math.round(((1 - a) * backgroundB) + (a * b))
  return "rgb("+r3+","+g3+","+b3+")";
}
```

1. Convert the background RGBA to RGB and fill the background with RGB.
2. Convert the foreground RGBA to RGB and fill the foreground text with RGB.

Comment: Interesting answer but I should have mentioned there are multiple layers. It needs to have alpha set to see the layers below it.

Comment: This answer will work if all the layers are monochromatic (as opposed to gradients or images). Just reduce all monochromatic layers from RGBA to RGB from the bottommost layer to the topmost layer.

Comment: Each layer is a text console so it wouldn't be a solid color below it but a font character. Is there no way to do it using a sequence of globalCompositeOperation calls? Accessing the buffer data is too slow and using drawImage is also a bottleneck.

Comment: Sigh...It would have been nice to know these things in the original question. :-(  I'm still not sure what you're wanting. You want layers of text? Why not just layer text over text then? Anyway, to clear up one possible misconception on your part:  `drawImage` should not be a bottleneck--it's most often faster than compositing and certainly faster than `getImageData`

Comment: Are you trying to mimic the old phosphorus displays where the previous text is still visible in ghostly form? If so, (1) clear the canvas, (2) redraw the background color, (3) redraw the previous ghost text in with lower alpha than before, (4) draw the new text with a higher (beginning) alpha.

Comment: It's a DOS like game where there are essentially multiple layers. Think of many DOS screens layered upon each other with alpha.

Comment: Just draw each layer from the bottom up with your desired alpha for each layer.

Comment: That is what I am doing however I need to create a mask from the text character as each character can have a different alpha for the background and foreground (text) color.

Comment: What I need is something like:
beginPath
filltext
clip
fillrect

Comment: Evidently I'm lost in knowing what you need...please present an image.

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly what I'm trying to do:

```
                  ctx.clearRect(x, y, chr_width, chr_height);
                 ctx.save();
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.rect(x, y, chr_width, chr_height);
            ctx.clip();     

            if (fgcolor.a != 255) {
                ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(' + fgcolor.r + ', ' +  fgcolor.g + ', ' + fgcolor.b + ',' + (fgcolor.a / 255.0) + ')';

                ctx.fillText(String.fromCharCode(chr), x,y);

                var imgData=ctx.getImageData(x,y,chr_width,chr_height);
                for (var idx = 0; idx < imgData.data.length; idx+=4) {
                    if (! imgData.data[idx+3]) {
                        imgData.data[idx] = bgcolor.r;
                        imgData.data[idx+1] = bgcolor.g;
                        imgData.data[idx+2] = bgcolor.b;
                        imgData.data[idx+3] = bgcolor.a;
                    }
                }

                ctx.putImageData(imgData,x,y);
            }
            else {
                ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(' + bgcolor.r + ', ' +  bgcolor.g + ', ' + bgcolor.b + ',' + (bgcolor.a / 255.0) + ')';   
                ctx.fillRect(x, y, chr_width, chr_height);
                ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(' + fgcolor.r + ', ' +  fgcolor.g + ', ' + fgcolor.b + ',' + (fgcolor.a / 255.0) + ')';
                ctx.fillText(String.fromCharCode(chr), x,y);

            }

            ctx.globalAlpha = 1.0;

            ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-over';

            ctx.restore();
```

Are there any speedier ways of accomplishing this avoiding accessing the data directly? Thanks.